# I am trying to write a quickSort method as part of an assignment, but I keep getting a StackOverflow error in Java

Tags: java, sorting, stack-overflow

This is the code for my sorting attempt. After running for about ten minutes in Eclipse's debugger mode, I got a lot of StackOverFlow errors. This was my output display:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

at TestSorter.Tester.sort(Tester.java:6)

... (x112 repetitions of at TestSorter.Tester.sort(Tester.java:49))

at TestSorter.Tester.sort(Tester.java:49)

```
public static int[] sort(int[] a) {
                           int prod = (a.length)/2, b = lessThan(a, prod), c = greaterThan(a, prod), d = equalTo(a, prod);
    int[] first, last, mid;
    first = new int[b];
    last = new int[c];
    mid = new int[d];
    int[] fina = new int[a.length];
    int f = 0, l = 0, m = 0;

    if (isSorted(a))
        return a;

    for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        if (a[x] < prod) {
            first[f] = a[x];
            f++;
        }
        else if (a[x] > prod) {
            last[l] = a[x];
            l++;
        }
        else if (a[x] == prod) {
            mid[m] = a[x];
            m++;
        }
    }
    if (m == a.length)
        return a;

                           first = sort(first);

    last = sort(last);

    for (int x = 0; x < b; x++) {
        fina[x] += first[x];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < d; x++) {
        fina[x + b] = mid[x];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < c; x++) {
        fina[x + b + c] = last[x];
    }

    return fina;
}
```

My support methods are as follows:

```
private static int lessThan(int[] a, int prod) {
    int less = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        if (a[x] < prod) {
            less++;
        }
    }
    return less;
}

private static int greaterThan(int[] a, int prod) {
    int greater = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        if (a[x] > prod) {
            greater++;
        }
    }
    return greater;
}

private static int equalTo(int[] a, int prod) {
    int equal = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        if (a[x] == prod) {
            equal++;
        }
    }
    return equal;
}

private static boolean isSorted(int[] a) {
    for (int x = 0; x < a.length - 1; x++) {
        if (a[x] > a[x + 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: error are you seeing? Can you paste the error trace here.

Comment: Which line is the exception stacktrace referring to? Lines 6 and 49? Have you run this with a debugger to see how your variables and recursion are misbehaving?

Comment: check the terminating condition for the recursive function .generally a recursive function not being terminated properly is the reason for stack overflow.

Comment: The two lines which I have indented to an exterme are the lines 6 and 49. I checked the terminating condition by outright making it true. However, even that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the trouble is that your "prod" is not within the domain of your array.  Thus either "first" or "last" is the same size as the input array, and you have an infinite recursion.  Try setting prod to be an element in the array you are trying to sort.

Answer (score 1):

THREE POINTS:

1. The `pord` should be the mid-element of the array, NOT the half of the array's length.
   So, it should be `prod =a[(a.length) / 2]`,
   NOT `prod =(a.length) / 2`
2. If the array **first** only have 1 element, it does not need invoke the method `sort` any more.
   Also the **last**.
   So, add `if` statement:

   ```
   if (1 < first.length) {
       first = sort(first);
   }
   ```
3. When you append the element of `last` to fina, the index should be `x+b+d`, it means `first` elements(`b`) + `mid` elements(`d`). NOT `x+b+c`.
   So, change `fina[x + b + c] = last[x];` to `fina[x + b + d] = last[x];`

Well, the method `sort` maybe like this:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] a) {
    int prod =a[(a.length) / 2], b = lessThan(a, prod), c = greaterThan(a,
            prod), d = equalTo(a, prod);
    int[] first, last, mid;
    first = new int[b];
    last = new int[c];
    mid = new int[d];
    int[] fina = new int[a.length];
    int f = 0, l = 0, m = 0;

    if (isSorted(a) )
        return a;

    for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        if (a[x] < prod) {
            first[f] = a[x];
            f++;
        } else if (a[x] > prod) {
            last[l] = a[x];
            l++;
        } else if (a[x] == prod) {
            mid[m] = a[x];
            m++;
        }
    }
    if (m == a.length)
        return a;

    if (1 < first.length) {
        first = sort(first);
    }

    if (1 < last.length) {
    last = sort(last);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < b; x++) {
        fina[x] += first[x];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < d; x++) {
        fina[x + b] = mid[x];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < c; x++) {
        fina[x + b + d] = last[x];
    }

    return fina;
}
```